# Determine if datetime is within weekday schedule

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I would like to know whether a given datetime is specified within a dayparting schedule and its timezone.

Example:

Determine if `epoch=1537414453837` is within the schedule defined below:

Dayparting Timezone: Asia/Hong_Kong (subject to change)

Dayparting Schedule:

```
mon: 0900-2300
tue: 0900-2300
wed: 0900-2300
thu: 0900-2300
fri: 0900-2300
sat: 1000-2300
sun: 1000-2300
```

Comment: Isn't `epoch=1537414453837` a long long time in the future?  It's > 1000x bigger than the current epoch value (time.time() => 1537417525)

Comment: I think you need to define the week number (or Monday's date) to be able to work this out.  For example, which monday is it?

Comment: @Kingsley dude it's milliseconds...

Answer (score 1):

epoch time is independent of timezone. It is calculated from midnight - Jan 1 1970 in UTC timezone.No matter where you are currently, it shows the same epoch time everywhere.But you can convert a given epoch time to other timezone.

Use `pytz.all_timezones` to see all the available time zones.

Following is one of the approaches.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
epoch_time=1537414453837/1000 
weekdays = ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday')
weekends = ('Saturday', 'Sunday')

local_time=datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time, tz= pytz.timezone('Hongkong'))
hours = local_time.hour

day = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time).strftime("%A")
if (day in weekdays):
    if (hours in range(9,23)):
        print("its Dayparting Schedule and a weekday")
elif (day in weekends):
    if (hours in range(10,23)):
        print("its Dayparting Schedule and a weekend")
else:
    print("no such day")
```